# How to replace substrings depending on their position?

Tags: php

I want to change `#@this is a string&%` to `.this is a string*`.

Here's what I've tried but it doesn't work:

```
$content = "...this is a string...";

$new = str_replace("/[^#@](.*)[^&%]/", "/[^'.'](.*)[^'*']/", $content);

echo $new;
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: So all you need to replace is `...` with `.`? Why not `str_replace('...','.',$content)`?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte sorry I just edited the question

Comment: `[^...]` means "anything but a dot" at both ends. Matching dots at the string start would be `^\.\.\.` or `\.\.$` at the end. And the replacement pattern does not use regex syntax at all.

Comment: `str_replace`  doesn't support regex, use `preg_match` instead.

Answer (score 1):

`str_replace` doesn't support regex arguments, you can use [`preg_replace`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) instead, i.e.:

```
$content = "#@this is a string..";
$new = preg_replace( "/^#@(.*?)\.\.$/i", '.$1*', $content );
# .this is a string*
```

---

Regex Explanation:

[image]

---

[Ideone](https://ideone.com/yC7Dpx) - [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/9NKi7r/1).

Comment: Thanks for your answer Pedro. It works fine if this string but if i had some text to it, it doesn't work anymore. For example: `#@this is a string.. with some additional text`. Is there anyway to make it work?

Comment: You're welcome. Try removing the `^` and `$` from the regex. You can also play around with the regex101 example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) function

```
$content = "...this is a string...";

$count = 0;
$new = preg_replace_callback("/(\.\.\.)/", function($match) use(&$count) {
    $count++;
    return str_repeat('.', $count);
}, $content);

echo $new;
```

This way, every match in your regex will run inside the function, and then you can create some logic to replace as you wish.
Just return what you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
$pattern = "%^[\.]+(.+[^\.])[\.]+$%";
$str = "...this is a string...";
$new = preg_replace($pattern, '..$1.', $str);


^       from start
[\.]+   dots, 1 or more
(       start subgroup
.+      any char...
[^\.]   ...but not dot
)       subgroup end
[\.]+$  dots, one or more, to the end.
```